# Calculate Value depending on other cells and append the existing value automatically

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have to work something in an excel sheet.

If you see the below example, I need to calculate the value in the 1st cell - `Calculate Value` depending on the values in the cells `UK`, `Ireland`, `France` and `US`.

I havent found how to get this done.

This excel sheet will have to be used for about 50,000 records and need a solution such that the value is calculated automatically when and if I enter a value in the other cells.

Another thing to note, I need to append the value in the 'Calculate Value' and not replace any existing value.

Every column has an indicator so for Ireland its IRL, UK its UK, France its FR and so on. So if a value exists in one of the columns (Ireland, UK, France..) the Calculated Value cell should show the codes as comma separated. 
Hope this makes sense. Sorry if i dont make much sense, let me know and ill explain further.

Tried using IFS but that only looks at current conditions and not all of them together

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried? I see your template, but there is no sample date nor expected results.

Comment: I have tried using IFS statements but to no use, as the value has to be appended to the existing value and i have 25 columns where i need to check the values of. I know a VBA code / Macro can be used but i am unsure how to use that. Conditional formatting also isnt uselful here as it only highlights the cell not calculate the value.

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried and how you want the "Calculated Value" to be related to the other values. Now you have "FR, US" related to values "4 and 5" but related how? 4 + 5? 4 x 5? ect.

Comment: There is no easy way for that. This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025871/how-to-concatenate-values-in-multiple-cells-based-on-a-condition

Comment: Thanks Mate, that post helped. I had tried to use concat inside the IFS, didnt think of trying IF inside a concatinate function...it will be a long ended condition but this works

Comment: So in this case the formula that i have used and that works is CONCATINATE(IF(B2<>"","UK, ",""),IF(B3<>"","IRL, ",""),IF(B4<>"","FR, ",""),IF(B5<>"","US, ","")) with 23 such columns, the formula is going to be a massive one and not very maintainable. Was hoping to use some kind of a macro so that will be easily maintainable by a not so experienced excel user when and if i have to add new columns

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),"UK, ","")&IF(ISNUMBER(C2),"Irl,","")

I'm assuming the values are numbers, but you can use isblank or a similar type of function.